# how to filter background grid on a scanned paper in PDF

Tags: pdf, filter, background, scanning

I have a scanned pdf document. The original document is handwritten and the paper used has a block grid in the background. I wanted to print the document and I was wondering if i could delete the background block filter of the paper and print just the written part.

Answer (score 2):

Every image processing job is different so there may be many ways to do this.  Can you first post a picture of the page so we can tell what could work and what wouldn't work.

Is the image in color or B/W ?
Are the lines a different color to the text ?
What resolution is the image scanned at ?
Is the image skewed ?

Most likely, you will need to convert the PDF to an image format and use an image processing function called line removal (with repair) to remove the lines.  Unfortunatley the best solutions are commercial and not cheap.

Comment: Agreed. A scanned document as PDF is usually just JPEG- or TIFF-like bytes embedded inside the PDF, effectively.

Comment: *Most likely, you will need to convert the PDF to an image format* - more likely not "convert to an image" but "extract the embedded image".which is a lossless process.